# Comparing two types in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm looking for a way to compare two types in Dart, and get `True` when they are the same.

I have a method:

```dart
SomeItemType exampleMethod<SomeItemType>(Map<String, dynamic> value) {
    if (SomeItemType.toString() == 'BuiltMap<String, String>') {
      return BuiltMap<String, String>.from(value) as SomeItemType;
    }
    // (...)
}
```

in which I must check if the type-parameter `SomeItemType` is actually equal to the type `BuiltMap<String, String>` or not.
The only way I found so far is the above string comparions, which is not too elegant in my opinion.

I have tried to following solutions, but they did not work out for me:

```dart
SomeItemType is BuiltMap<String, String>
// returns False

SomeItemType == BuiltMap<String, String>
// error: The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

BuiltMap<String, String> is SomeItemType
// error: The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
```

Comment: Can you add more details to your example? It is not really possible to know the issue without knowing how you are calling `exampleMethod`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to detect whether a *type variable* holds a type which is "the same" as some known type.

I'd probably not go for *equality* in that check, I'd just check if the type of the variable is a subtype of the known type.

You can do that like:

```dart
class _TypeHelper<T> {}
bool isSubtypeOf<S, T>() => _TypeHelper<S>() is _TypeHelper<T>;
// or just ...           => <S>[] is List<T>;
...
  if (isSubtypeOf<T, BuiltMap<String, String>>()) { ... }
```

If you want to check type equality, then you have to decide what type equality means.
The simplest is "mutual subtyping", which would mean:

```dart
bool isMutualSubtypes<S, T>() => isSubtypeOf<S, T>() && isSubtypeOf<T, S>();
// or                         => isSubtypeOf<S Function(S), T Function(T)>();
// or                         => isSubtypeOf<void Function<X extends T>() Function(),
//                                           void Function<X extends S>() Function()>();
```

This will accept, e.g., `isMutualSubtypes<void, dynamic>()` because both types are top types.

Type *identity* is much harder to check because the language itself doesn't have that notion. If types are mutual subtypes, they are considered equivalent at run-time (we distinguish `void` and `dynamic` statically, but not at run-time).
You can *try* something like:

```dart
bool isSameType<S, T>() => S == T;
```

but equality of `Type` objects is very underspecified, and not guaranteed to work any better than mutual subtyping.
Definitely don't use string comparison:

```dart
// Don't use!
bool isSameType<S, T>() => "$S" == "$T"; // BAD!
```

because it's possible to have different types with the same name.

Comment: `"You need to detect whether a type variable holds a type which is "the same" as some known type."`
This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to check if a variable pointed to a function. This worked for me `variable is function` - the word `is`